# cognos tm1 linking cubes

Tags: cube, cognos-tm1

i have one cube A which contains, lets say, 4 dimensions: name, location, amount, sum total. and other cube b: location, currency, exchange rates.

Now i want that if user inputs something in cube A according to the location , then TM1 must take the corresponding exchange rates from cube B , multiples the amount(from cube A) with exchange rate(from cube B) and gives the sum total in cube A.

What all rules and links can i apply for this.. need some help..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to write following rule in cube A:

['Sum Total'] = N: ['amount'] * DB('B', !location, 'CurrencyName', 'ExchangeRateName');